# Cannot change the size of text box

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Im using the following code and I cannot change the size of the text box to make it bigger than 700,how can I change it to 1000?

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Service, new { @class = "col-md-2 oper-label" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Service, new { @style = "width: 700px;" })
       </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the language that you are using, but if you just use an HTML `<textarea>` it will work.

#### [Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/wsBAIXXONV)

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" style="width: 700px;"></textarea>
      </div>
</div>
```

This code will produce a `<textarea>` that is 700 pixels wide like this:
[image]

Adjust the width to change the width of the textarea.  Another option would be to do this, which produces a textarea that will be approximately 80% of the browser width:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want to chage the height,just the width ,how should I do that ?

Comment: There is no change to the height.  You can adjust the width by using inline `style="width"` (1st example above) or adjust `col-md-10` (2nd example)

Comment: thanks but how should I send the data from the textarea to my model?

Comment: That would be a separate question.  You have to make sure your inputs are in a form and you submit them.  You should be able to find more info on SO or by Googling.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just change **class="col-md-10"** to **class="col-md-11"** (or col-md-12) or simply remove `<div class="col-md-10">` ?

Check this link out for more information about bootstrap grid system : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic